# Sudden change in the area of research

Tags: phd, research-process, advisor

I am a third-year Ph.D student of computer science and engineering (I joined a direct PhD program after my bachelor’s in computer science). I am working on theoretical computer science.

In the first two years, I did the course work plus some survey of the field called theoretical computer science. To get anything published in XYZ is more challenging (as well as requires more time) than the abc. I am more interested in the ABC than the XYZ. It is not that I am not interested in ABC side, I am very much. In the first two years I have explored XYZ side. I also did three to four courses related to ABC techniques.

Now my supervisor is saying that I should “be open to both XYZ techniques as well as ABC techniques”. I am confused what to do. Is it normal? I have not started my thesis yet.

Comment: I think your advisor knows more about this that we do.  Follow his advice.  If you have questions on this, discuss it with him.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking as a combinatorist, you'll be better off being open to both subfields from a knowledge point of view.

Remember: what you choose to write your thesis on does not determine what you'll study for the rest of your life. Especially when we are talking about two subfields so closely related.

If you want to be at a university the state of the fields now matters pretty little, comparatively to the date of the fields in 10-15 years. If you want to enter industry, it's unlikely that the subject of your dissertation matters much at all (field, sure. But subsubdiscipline? Not at all).

Listen to your advisor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are saying subsubdiscipline does not matter, but from research perspective to me it still appears that subsubdiscipline is also very much important or are you trying to say that we can change subsubdiscipline after doing Ph.D any time.

Comment: I said it doesn't matter what you write your thesis on if you go into industry, not that it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: But yes you have ample opportunity to change your subsubdiscipline in an academic career. Writing a thesis on one subject doesn't lock you into that topic for life.

Answer (score 1):

It's really important in research to be open to whatever techniques will be useful in the problems you're working on.  Of course that doesn't mean you can or should be an expert in everything, but you should be aware of at least the fundamentals of topics closely related to what you're working on.  Maybe some aspect of the problem will be much easier from a different point of view, and you won't have to be an expert in that field just familiar with it.  Or even just knowing what kinds of problems experts in that field can solve can lead to knowing when to collaborate.

My feeling from reading your question is that you've misunderstood your advisor.  It sounds like you think you need to suddenly drop all the stuff you've learned and instead become an expert in a different area.  I doubt that's what your advisor is saying.  Your advisor said "be open to both techniques" not change your main area of expertise.